# Send a single left mouse click c# console app

Tags: c#, click, mouse, sendkeys

I want to send just a single left mouse click in a way that SendKeys.Send works. I have a program where the mouse moves to a certain position and I have that working but I have no idea how to do a single mouse click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console App Mouse-Click X Y Coordinate Detection/Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944481/console-app-mouse-click-x-y-coordinate-detection-comparison)

Comment: Please clarify your question (edit and improve your question; please do **NOT** explain here in a comment!!!): Do you have a console application that should be able to manipulate mouse coordinates and send click events (to other windows/programs); or do you want your console application to receive and react to mouse clicks?