# Is it possible to make a Clickable Text in c# (ConsoleApplication)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, visual-studio-2019, cosmos

So, let me say...
I have a C# Visual Studio CosmosOS Kernel: https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos,

I have a text: `CLICK ME`

Is it possible to execute Code when i click the Text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console App Mouse-Click X Y Coordinate Detection/Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944481/console-app-mouse-click-x-y-coordinate-detection-comparison)

Comment: i have something like CosmosOS, is it possible in this?