# if Right button pressed on console

Tags: c

Good morning,
I would like to know if my right mouse button is held down. 
For this I thought of System.Windows.Input.Mouse but I get this error if I execute the following code:

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (Mouse.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {

            }
        }
```

Error : **Unmanaged exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread must be in STA mode, as required by the name**

Is there an alternative or something that would work as a console?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971246/17034

Answer (score 0):

Try using it inside a function like this :

```
private void PressLeftButton(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Left Mouse Button is pressed");
    }
}
```