# I need help to detect when left mouse button is held and not clicking

Tags: c#, macros, hook, mouse, mouselistener

Recently im coding a macro, I need to make that if you left click, and not hold the left mouse button the click while the macro is enabled it's not gonna work

```
while ( GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) != 0 && isMacroEnabled && isHoldingLeftClick && isntClicking ) {
    // Macro code
}
```

Comment: Do you use WinForms app?

Comment: no, I don't, I personally prefer console app so I can use ImGui.NET

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944481/console-app-mouse-click-x-y-coordinate-detection-comparison